# ConnectionString Builder in Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to convert an old project c# to asp net core and to the EF core 2.0 and I can't find the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.

```
public string GetEntityConnectionString(string databaseName, string metadata)
{
    string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    string providerString = GetConnectionString(databaseName);


    System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
    new System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
```

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the
>   namespace  'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because EF Core does not support what was known "database first" approach of older EF versions, so there are no edmx files, and so there is no use for EF specific connection strings (`metadata=res:...` < this kind of connection strings). From that it follows that there is no use for `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` class, which is used to create such connection strings.

So when porting, just remove your whole `GetEntityConnectionString` method and use your `GetConnectionString` instead, together with `UseSqlServer`, `UsePgsql` and similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

You may set connection on Context. Try override **OnConfiguring** method:

```
    public class CommonDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CommonDbContext(DbContextOptions<CommonDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=user;Password=pwd;Connection Timeout=60");
        }
    }
```